# Can an SVM perform better than an Ideal Observer?

Tags: bayesian, svm, naive-bayes

Under what circumstances is the above not true? It seems that in fields like vision science, the ideal observer is preferred against other classifiers when the underlying distributions are known for psychophysics experiments. However, the low-level psychophysical stimuli is usually not as complex and diverse as other classification problems such as multiview object recognition or text classification.

I also wanted to get a confusion out of my head: Is an Ideal Observer the same as a Naive Bayes Classifier? Because mathematically they look very alike.

Ideal observer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_observer_analysis

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggests, the ideal observer is ... ideal, in that it makes the best possible use of the information available to it and cannot be beat, even by very sophisticated techniques. However, keep in the mind that an ideal observer isn't really a classification algorithm *per se*. Unlike a support vector machine or Naive Bayes, its purpose isn't making predictions.

Instead, perceptual experiments use ideal observer models to provide an upper bound on subjects' performance: if someone could perfectly(!) analyse *this* information in order to make a decision about *that*, how well could they do? We can then compare these theoretical calculations with data from actual subjects using the same data to make the same decision.

If your ideal observer model is choosing between different (known) probability distributions, then a Bayesian classifier is optimal (see this [short summary](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/jkivinen/opetus/iml/2013/Bayes.pdf)). If you have only a single feature, then this is the same as the a Naive Bayes classifer.

Comment: I believe that a Naive Bayes is also the same as an Ideal Observer if all the dimensions of the input feature vector are statistically independant! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yup, you're absolutely correct. A Bayesian ideal observer for $\ge$ 2 dimensions would have the covariance term in its formula, but if you knew they were uncorrelated, it would also look like the Naive Bayes equation.